# How do I login with PayPal to save user_id?

Tags: ruby, paypal

Is it possible to use a "login with PayPal" button through the PayPal API? I want to use it as a twitter signin to link your paypal account once to the app, then have it store a `user_id`.

Is this possible?

---

I want some kind of '**connect to paypal**' behaviour. Think about a shop where goods are sold and get paid to the shop onwers paypal account. The shop owner must verify (connnect) once his paypal account and the app will then know where all payments must go.

It is also possible to just ask for the shop owners paypal email account, but this ain't really low level in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

If this even was posssible to do I wouldn't do such a thing for authentication.

The reason is, the user could easily assign that he has to pay for every login with this procedure.